# How does HDFS download files?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If the Hadoop replication is set to 3 and I use **hadoop dfs -get** to download a file, how many datanodes are transpoting data to me simultaneously ? Is the download method a parallel way like RAID, or just read datanodes one by one sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

The data is read sequentially from only one node.

Note that the file might be multiple blocks, in which case the blocks are pulled from different nodes.

Comment: any reason for reading sequentially and how to configure for reading in parallel?